# Labels on the same line, not under each other

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this:

```
<div>
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dd>
            <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)</h5>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)</h5>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

It is a firstname lastname. But they are showing under each other like this:

> Albert
>   Newton

and it has to be:

> Albert Newton

Comment: You could use a table

Comment: @user3444160 the `table`-tag is considered bad practice since 2000-late :)

Comment: Main point here is **why** you're using `<dl>` with `dl-horizontal` but without `<dt>`. Should `<dt>` be used for `Html.LabelFor()`? If not why don't you simply drop all `<dl>` stuff in favor of a single `<div>` (or whatever) with both fields?

Comment: H5 is a block-element as far as I know... change it to a span or whatever inline-element

Comment: @HimBromBeere why change the tag, when you can change the style via css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqpgdgv8/1/)

```
dd {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

dd element must be display inline so you can just add dd to your css and see

if dd is **bootstrap's** element, then you must override with !important tag

```
dd {
   display:inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair because he's suggesting to make horizontal with inline-block...a vertical list. Moreover dl list in this case makes no sense at all. So, yes, it works for such snippet in the context of this small snippet but it'll mess CSS if OP will ever use dl somewhere else in the proper way and it won't help future readers to solve a similar problem (well it doesn't even help OP to understand his problem). That's why my -1. _"**Q**: How to format hard drive? **A**: format c: **Q**: Why you need it? **A**: to delete temporary files"_

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti did you see that he mentioned that he was using bootstrap, dl-horizontal class could be my custom class couldn't be? I get your approach, I agree with you but when you down voting with a really specific reason, I suggest you to make a comment. With this question format, this is the best answer that I could prove

Comment: Well `dl-horizontal` is Bootstrap class for an horizontal aligned `<dl>` list (where title `<dt>` and description `<dd>` are side by side, not where each `<dd>` is stacked horizontally like `span`). I agree you can't suggest (much) better than this without more info but that's why we have comments (to ask for clarifications). That said you're right I had to leave a comment to explain downvote!

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti no offense, just thought some hint for the author would be nice, so (s)he can elaborate ;)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair no offense! You were right, I had to leave a comment but I commented question and I was lazy to write twice!